# How to set default credentials in Jenkins using Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to write my first 'Groovy script' in Jenkins and using SVN

My requirement is to create a 'free style job' from another 'Jenkins job' using groovy

Using the following code, I am able to create a 'free style job' via 'groovy'

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
import hudson.model.FreeStyleProject;
import hudson.tasks.Shell;
import hudson.triggers.*;


def feature_branch = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("FEATURE_BRANCH")

job = Jenkins.instance.createProject(FreeStyleProject, feature_branch)

job.buildersList.add(new Shell('echo hello world'))
job.scm = new hudson.scm.SubversionSCM("http://base/branches/mybranche")

job.save()
```

Though the job is created by default 'SCM Credentials' to set to 'None' in the 'newly created job'

1) How can I set the 'default credentials' using groovy from 'Global credentials' ?
2) How can I add a 'build parameter' via groovy?  Again not much information available on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for sometime, I found the following which enabled me to set the 'default credentials' of a job

```
job.scm.locations[0].credentialsId = "Hash-value-of-credential"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use something like this:

```
job('FEATURE_BRANCH') {
    steps {
       shell("echo 'hello world'")
    }  
    scm {
      svn {
        location('http://base/branches/mybranche') {
          credentials('crd_svn')
         }
      }
    }
}
```

crd_svn is the identifier of the credentials that are managed by the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin).

And [Job DSL plugin page](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#)   could be useful.

Comment: job("FEATURE_BRANCH') resulted in exception.  I tried modifying the statement in many ways, but it erred as follows  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, Script1$_run_closure1) values: [FEATURE_BRANCH, Script1$_run_closure1@1c95c1b]

Comment: Did you add `def job = Jenkins.getInstance();` before this code ?